# How to manipulate excel to create statements?

Tags: excel, concatenation, string-concatenation, vba

I have a lot of data within Excel that I need to manipulate into statements that will then be copied into another program to run data extractions.

`OBJECT    FIELD    LOW`

```
S_DATASET ACTVT    33

S_DATASET ACTVT    34

S_DATASET FILENAME
```

For example the first line of above statement needs to be transformed into "OBJECT = "S_DATASET" .and. FIELD = "ACTVT" .and. LOW = "33"", and so on. For some of these tables I have up to 268 lines, so I need to find a way to automate it.

Would this be easy to do within Excel, or would there possibly be a better way of concatenating the information together?

Comment: Do you always have fixed number of parameters (columns)? Can column titles change or they are always the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with simple formulas. Like

```
="OBJECT = """ & A1 & """ .and. FIELD = """ & B1 & """ .and. LOW = """ & C1 & """"
```